# Javascript regex to get content from character to character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some custom Markdown that includes the dollar sign (`$`).

This create markdown like this:

```
$ something
# Hello all
How are you?

$ Foobar
# Something else
```

***I'm looking for a regex from dollar sign to dollar sign.***

So the output would be:

```
var i = ["$ something\n# Hello all\nHow are you?\n", "$ foobar\n# Something else"]
```

Note:
This is what I have to get all content after the dollar sign:
`/\$ [ \t]*([^\n\r]*)/g` ([example](http://regexr.com/3ch5i))

Comment: Doesn't `/\$[^$]*/g` get all the required substrings? I do not see a point in using any lookaheads here.

Comment: Nope, this is only one row, I need everything _until_ next `$`

Comment: How come it is one row? `[^$]` matches newline symbols. Check https://regex101.com/r/cH9jO0/1 and https://jsfiddle.net/1cm4dtpf/.

Comment: True, _but_ it get _everything_ not from `$` till `$`. Example: http://regexr.com/3ch8u

Comment: There are 2 matches, see https://jsfiddle.net/1cm4dtpf/. I just wonder why you specified one `\n` at the end of the first matched substring - there are 2. I get `["$ something\n# Hello all\nHow are you?\n\n","$ Foobar\n# Something else"]`.

Comment: @stribizhev my mistake, you are correct, thanks, +1 for you :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the output you are expecting, you could use the following:

```
/(\$[^$]*(?=\$|$))/g
```

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/eI6mR8/1)

It will match *until* the next `$` (or the end of the string) by utilizing a positive lookahead.

- `\$[^$]*` - match the `$` character literally followed by zero or more non-`$` characters.
- `(?=\$|$)` - Positive lookahead to match until the next `$` character literally, or the end of the string, `$`.

Output:

```
["$ something\n# Hello all\nHow are you?\n", "$ foobar\n# Something else"]
```

Comment: Your regex returns `\n\n` at the end of first match. If you change it to `/(\$[^$]*(?=\n|$))/g` it returns one `\n`, as expected by OP.

Comment: @EganWolf Good point. However, that would always require a `\n` character before the `$`, and it would break in a case [like this](https://regex101.com/r/mD8vB0/1). If the OP does, in fact, only want zero or one newlines, then `(\$[^$]*?\n?(?=\n*\$|$))` should cover the scenarios - https://regex101.com/r/hJ1dP5/1 .. thanks for pointing that out by the way.

Comment: Note that the lookahead is useless since the use of `[^$]*` makes it "implicit".

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to what I need, I would like to include 'something' though.
Like: `(\$ something[^$]*(?=\$|$))`, this is correct, but now the only thing is that it needs to go to the next `$ something` instead of `$`.

Comment: @BobvanLuijt Like `(\$ something(?:[\s\S](?!\$ something))*)`? It seems to work here - https://regex101.com/r/dL0gM0/1

Comment: Yes, that's it, I've made `?= something` thanks.
Kan you please explain the `...(?! something))*)` part? Thanks!

Comment: @BobvanLuijt It's a negative lookahead that will match any characters one or more times if it is not followed by `(?!\$ something)`. So it essentially matches *until* each `$ something` line.

Comment: You have changed the requirements in the comments. Why not ask a separate question? BTW, I provided a more efficient regex for that in my comment below. Do not use tempered greedy token since it will test each position and unrolled regexps grab matches linearly.

Comment: I removed my answer. If you need to match from `$ something` till next, you should think of using an *unroll-the-loop*ed regex like [`/\$ something(?:[^$]*(?:\$(?! something)[^$])*)*/g`](https://regex101.com/r/nU2sZ4/1). But it is a very different question. Josh suggest using a tempered greedy token, but it is very inefficient compared to my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negation based regex:

```
/\$[^$]*\$/g
```

`[^$]*` will match anything but `$` that includes newlines.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qY2sT6/1)

Comment: Mr @anubhava, you are correct. Thanks, you're awesome :-P

Comment: Hmm did my answer not work for you? I think accepted answer is same as what I posted about 6 hours ago :P

Comment: Yes, it did, it did. But @stribizhev was very helpful too. I can't decide and I would give you both +25 if I could.
But I thought, you are already 316k and therefor a boss. Hope my gratitude is enough :-)
Hope the +1 helps too...

Comment: No no it is always OP's choice to select any answer as accepted. I was wondering in this case because I had posted the same answer long time back. No issues and thanks for +1